# Philippines dollar (peso) sign ₱ show incorrectly in android

Tags: android, utf-8, utf

I have working on android app and showing the

Philippines peso sign in UTF 8

It show, but it show as P with one line instead of two line (₱), how to fix it?

Thanks

**Update:**

Currently using \u20B1 in string.xml and setText in java,

but still one line only. Do I need something like below:

```
String name = "";
try {
    name = new String(c.getString("NAME").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

String decodedName = Html.fromHtml(name).toString();
```

Thanks again for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are implementing it right now. However, as far as I'm aware, make sure you are using the right character: `U+20B1`

Here are some links to help:

http://graphemica.com/%E2%82%B1
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b1/index.htm

Comment: also, in some of my testing device , it works and some do not works, so there is no way I can fix it in coding? thanks

Comment: If a character is showing up, there probably isn't an error with the code. Are you sure there are no references to `\u20A7` in your code?

Comment: yes, haven't use that , that means google system problem? I also attempt using &#8369; but still one line only.

Comment: It's quite weird, if using \u20A7 , then it is a symbol : "Pt", is it device encoding problem or how to check my android phone is using UTF-8?

Comment: Hmm... If you said that it works on some devices I would assume it would be an isolated problem with the specific systems- perhaps with certain fonts. Personally I've never ran into this problem. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: no problem , really helpful information provided, if "Pt" would give any hints of that? For those not working device , \u20B1 is P with one line and \u20A7 is "Pt", and for those working , \u20B1 is P with two line and  \u20A7 is "Pts" , seems the encode set is different

Comment: This is totally weird! Although this seems to have been fixed in API 21 and above; I can notice a 'P' clearly strikethrough with two parallel lines but not in API<21.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually copy and paste the peso(₱) sign directly to Android Studio.